# Lock-free with 8byte CAS only? C++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, thread-safety, atomic

I am using a 64-bit x86 system limited to a 8 byte maximum for compare and swap operations. Since pointers are 8-bytes and I require a counter to avoid the ABA problem, is it possible to modify the upper 16 bits of the pointer which are unused to store a counter?

```
pointer_as_dec = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&node); // Node address
pointer_as_dec+(1LLU<<48); // Initialize the counter in one of the upper bits
```

Is it possible to use the __sync_bool_compare_and_swap function to store the modified pointer address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't guaranteed to work according to any standard—the only thing you're really allowed to do with a pointer cast to an int is cast it back to a pointer unchanged. But practically, it will work on any x86_64 platform, and almost any other current platform. And obviously you weren't expecting gcc-specific, x86_64-specific code to be portable. So, no problem here.

Also, `uintptr_t` is not one of the [supported types](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp121.linux.doc%2Fcompiler_ref%2Fbif_gcc_atomic_bool_comp_swap.html) for gcc atomic functions—but it's completely compatible with `unsigned long long int`, which is. (If you're worried about that, you can always add a second cast…) So, no problem here either.

Meanwhile, `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` doesn't care that you're smuggling a pointer in that `uintptr_t`; as far as it's concerned, it's just an unsigned 64-bit integer. So, no problem here.

Can you really be sure that the top 16 bits are always empty? In x86_64 linux, they are for your normal user memory. They may *not* be for pointers to kernel memory or memory-mapped hardware, and they may not be on other x86_64 systems—but if not, they'll be all 1s instead. And as Brendan points out, that's guaranteed for anything running on x86_64 hardware without 128-bit CAS.* So, if you need to point at such memory or port to such systems, just use 15 bits instead of 16. (And even if that weren't true, assuming you're pointing to, say, 64-bit-aligned objects, you've also got 6 free bits at the other end of the pointer, which you could use instead/in addition.) So, no problem here either.

---

* Except in the highly unlikely event that AMD or Intel or someone else decides to change the virtual address size and also decides to take away 128-bit CAS…

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is helpful. Since _sync_bool_cas takes a pointer to a memory location as its first argument, how would I pass the number stored in the uintptr_t (rather the uint64_t after I have cast that) and not a pointer to the uintptr_t variable itself?

Comment: @user3217789: You can't use the munged-up-disguised-pointer in the `uintptr_t` as a *pointer*, you can only use it as a _value_. Whatever structure you have that references some object that needs to be CAS'd, you store the munged pointers _there_, instead of real pointers. Then you CAS them by using the address right there in the struct. And you have to strip off the bits to deref them.

Comment: @user3217789: And think about it, what good would it do to have a counter on the pointer itself? The whole point of CAS is to verify that the 64 bits of memory being pointed to haven't changed since you last checked. Nobody cares whether you have a new pointer to that 64 bits of memory, just what's there. And remember, the whole reason you need CAS in the first place is that other objects will have other pointers to the same address.

Comment: You can be sure that if the pointer is valid, the top 16-bits are either all zeros or all set, as valid (canonical) virtual address are actually 48-bit and "sign extended" to 64-bit. At least in theory, eventually Intel or AMD may add a different way to do paging in long mode and increase the virtual address space size (but that won't be happening soon, and 128-bit CAS already exists). There might also be a few "always zero due to alignment" least significant bits if you're desperate.

Comment: @Brendan: Almost all of that was already in the answer. But thanks for pointing out that the all-0s-or-all-1s is guaranteed on _any_ x86_64 platform without 128-bit CAS; added that to the text.

Comment: "`uintptr_t` is not one of the supported types", what do you mean by that? This is only a `typedef` necessarily pointing to one of the basic types that should be covered by this.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Neither C nor POSIX requires that these typedefs match any of the specific standard types anywhere, just that they match some built-in integral type of the right width. See [POSIX `<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) for example.

Comment: @abarnert, wrong. C stipulates that this is an "unsigned integer type" and clearly defines what that can be. In particular it can't be some arbitrary "built-in integral type". Extended integer type may be specified by some platforms, but I don't know of any that has them.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, it's _an_ unsigned integer type. It's not _a particular_ unsigned integer type. In fact, 7.18 explicitly says "Some of these types may denote implementation-defined extended integer types". So you can't say that C guarantees this to be the same as `unsigned long long` (even ignoring the fact that C doesn't require either of those types to be exactly 64 bits…). However, 6.2.5 and 6.2.6.2 guarantee that the values will have the same representations. Therefore, just as I said in the answer, it's still safe to use.

Comment: @JensGustedt: (Since we're getting technical, I'm using 64-bit as a shortcut for "with 64 value bits and 0 padding bits".)

Comment: @abarnert thanks, I clearly misunderstood the CAS operation. Implemented & tested using the upper 16bits as a counter and works without any issues.